# There is X and X

Tags: idioms

In his preface to the revised version of “The Tragic Muse,” Henry James writes:

> There may in its absence be life, incontestably, as “The Newcomes” has
>   life, as “Les Trois Mousquetaires”, as Tolstoi’s “Peace and War” …
>   **There is life and life**, and as waste is only life sacrificed and thereby prevented from “counting.”

I’m aware of the idiomatic structure *“There is X and X,”* which can be perceived as “A certain X can be different from another X” or something like that.

But in the fragment above, this structure doesn’t seem to make sense.

I would re-word it as “Everyone around is talking about life…”

The versions are:

1. I’m wrong, the idiomatic structure is OK.
2. I’m right, and my understanding is correct.
3. Something else.

Comment: Generally, I would avoid trying to second guess a writer like Henry James. What do you mean by idiomatic structure? The idiom is fine there. In any case, rewording as you have done completely changes the meaning there and sounds, well, bad. [sorry]

Comment: I'm not trying to second guess. It's about understanding.

Comment: Please post the whole sentence. It means: there is life and there is life but waste is not  one of them and does not count as one of them of those types of life.

Comment: To Lambie: It's the whole sentence. The next one is: "I delight in a deep-breathing economy of an organic form."

Comment: No, I just looked it up; ***there is a comma.*** [Gutenberg copy] There is life and life, and as waste is only life sacrificed and thereby prevented from "counting," I delight in a deep-breathing economy and an organic form. as here=since.

Comment: Not only is what follows relevant to (possible) understanding of the structure but the definition of "its" in "There may in its absence be life" would also help.

Answer (score 1):

Introduction - The Tragic Muse by Henry James

> We have heard it maintained, we well remember, that such things are
>   "superior to art"; but we understand least of all what that may mean,
>   and we look in vain for the artist, the divine explanatory genius, who
>   will come to our aid and tell us. There is life and life, and as waste
>   is only life sacrificed and thereby prevented from "counting," I
>   delight in a deep-breathing economy and an organic form. My business
>   was accordingly to "go in" for complete pictorial fusion, some such
>   common interest between my two first notions as would, in spite of
>   their birth under quite different stars, do them no violence at all.

It means: there is life and there is life but waste is not one of them and therefore does not count as one of those types of life.

Furthermore ***"as"*** means ***"since"*** here: since waste means a sacrificed life, it does not count as one of the lives in the idiom "there is life and life". [bolding doesn't work for me for some reason, sorry]

> [Introduction - The Tragic Muse](http://We%20have%20heard%20it%20maintained,%20we%20well%20remember,%20that%20such%20things%20are%20%22superior%20to%20art%22;%20but%20we%20understand%20least%20of%20all%20what%20that%20may%20mean,%20and%20we%20look%20in%20vain%20for%20the%20artist,%20the%20divine%20explanatory%20genius,%20who%20will%20come%20to%20our%20aid%20and%20tell%20us.%20There%20is%20life%20and%20life,%20and%20as%20waste%20is%20only%20life%20sacrificed%20and%20thereby%20prevented%20from%20%22counting,%22%20I%20delight%20in%20a%20deep-breathing%20economy%20and%20an%20organic%20form.%20My%20business%20was%20accordingly%20to%20%22go%20in%22%20for%20complete%20pictorial%20fusion,%20some%20such%20common%20interest%20between%20my%20two%20first%20notions%20as%20would,%20in%20spite%20of%20their%20birth%20under%20quite%20different%20stars,%20do%20them%20no%20violence%20at%20all.)

Comment: http://www.gutenberg.org/files/20085/20085-h/20085-h.htm This link might work better.